# Storing User Settings in Backbone

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am fairly new to Backbone so my difficultly here may be related to a fundamental misunderstanding of the concepts. My question is, what is the best way to store user settings in Backbone> The settings have a variety of uses including determining how views should render. It seems a waste to attempt to request all of these resources on page load. Part of the issue is that each View corresponds to a model (the data being represented) but in some respects the data being represented includes the a subset of the user settings and the other model. Furthermore, it's not like each setting (or any group of settings) has a unique ID and could be represented in the way the Backbone seems to want them to and will need query strings to be referred to when communicating with the server.

Perhaps this should really be a non-issue but I can't quite see how to accomplish something like this in Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always inherit your models from a base model which contains a user attribute, so models will have that information with them, such as:

```
MyAppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    user: {}
});
```

You can also store the user object in a global object, and no, you shouldn't request them on page load.  If you can embed it into the page, say you were using ASP.NET MVC with Razor templating, you could have this inside your `.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ViewBag used just to illustrate point
    window.app.myUser = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.User));
</script>
```

You could then have the user attribute defined as `app.myUser`.

There's no reason for it to have its own backbone.model, but it wouldn't cause any problems to do so, either.

Comment: What I was really referring to was that if you have a very large number of settings, but very few if any are needed immediately (or even will be needed at all in a given session). You shouldn't load them in at the start. Instead, you should use AJAX when needed. However, I do not fully understand how that would work the way Backbone does it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? I don't understand what problem you're facing.